# adding multiple tables from one Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone suggest a solution for below:
I am taking inputs from a CSV file using javascript. On a button click, I would like to update two tables in HTML. I have set two dvis; dvCSV and alld.
When I click on button the table only gets updated in "alldc" not in "dvCSV".
If I remove var alld =......upto "alld.appendChild(table);" then only "dvCSV" table gets updated with the data.

```
var dvCSV = document.getElementById("dvCSV");
dvCSV.innerHTML = "";
dvCSV.appendChild(table);
                                         
var alld = document.getElementById("alld");
alld.innerHTML = "";
alld.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: There's only one `table`. Appending it to different elements doesn't clone it. -> [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

Comment: _"The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node. **If the given child is a reference to an existing node** in the document, appendChild() **moves it** from its current position to the new position (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node)."_

Comment: Thanks what's the solution for this? Do I need to use Node.CloneNode()? if yes, how to use in above code? Appreciate your help.